# What is the difference between @inlined and @@inline in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, inline

What is the difference between using @inlined and using @@inline after a function declaration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@@inline` is attached to a function or functor declaration while `@inlined` is attached to a function application.

```
let add x y = x + y [@@inline]
let z = (add[@inlined]) 1 2
```

You should refer [this](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/flambda.html) for more information.